# How to add and update data using the date range period (date from and to)?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like below

Stage 1

Table Name : Product

```
Date_From   Date_To     Available
01/03/2011  05/03/2011  5
06/03/2011  15/03/2011  6
```

Stage 2

If I update above table with below data

```
Date_From   Date_To     Available
04/03/2011  08/03/2011  4
10/03/2011  18/03/2011  2
```

Stage 3

I need output of Product table (Stage 1) like this, when update with stage 2 data at same time

```
Date_From   Date_To     Available
01/03/2011  03/03/2011  5
04/03/2011  08/03/2011  4
06/03/2011  15/03/2011  6
10/03/2011  18/03/2011  2
```

Hoping for your help

EDIT:

```
create table t (dt_from datetime,dt_to datetime, Available int)

insert into t values ('20110301','20110305',5)
insert into t values ('20110306','20110315',6)
```

run after trigger is created

```
--insert into t values ('20110304','20110308',4)
---insert into t values ('20110310','20110318',2)



SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt_from) rn FROM t

CREATE TRIGGER my_tr ON t FOR INSERT
AS

UPDATE t SET dt_to=(SELECT TOP 1  DATEADD(d,-1,dt_from) FROM inserted t1 WHERE dt_from
                    BETWEEN t.dt_from AND t.dt_to AND t.Available<>t1.Available)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  inserted t1 WHERE dt_from
                    BETWEEN t.dt_from AND t.dt_to AND t.Available<>t1.Available)
UPDATE t SET dt_from=(SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(d,1,dt_to) FROM inserted t1 WHERE dt_to
                    BETWEEN t.dt_from AND t.dt_to AND t.Available<>t1.Available)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  inserted t1 WHERE dt_to
                    BETWEEN t.dt_from AND t.dt_to AND t.Available<>t1.Available)
```

the above code is working fine , i get the below result

```
Date_From   Date_To     Available
01/03/2011  03/03/2011  5
04/03/2011  08/03/2011  4
09/03/2011  09/03/2011  6
10/03/2011  18/03/2011  2
```

---

But only one problem i facing is

```
insert into t values ('20110301','20110318',5)
```

it not get the correct result

i need result like below

```
Date_From   Date_To     Available
01/03/2011  18/03/2011  5
```

Hoping your help

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are trying to do, Why update the table with the replacement data instead of inserting 2 new rows?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: becasuse i want to update table with new data (Availaility)

Comment: What happens when you get a row that has a date_from/date_to that completely covers one already existing range?

Comment: ok.. if i add stage 2 data to the stage 1 data.. then how i display data from the table like stage 3

Comment: your trigger is **very dangerous** in that it only ever looks at the **first row** in the `Inserted` table and just plain ignores any possible additional rows......

Comment: @marc_s: The trigger uses UPDATE because it adjusts certain columns of the newly inserted data, I don't see anything wrong with that. But the fact that the trigger is designed to process only one row is bad indeed.

Comment: @user475464: It would be great if you described the logic of how the dates should be modified on the new rows in different cases. With the first example I more or less understand what you have done to the dates of the inserted rows. But I don't understand the logic of the second example, the one which you say is not working. Why the dates should be left the same? Please describe the complete logic of how it should work.

Comment: @user475464: And in the future please do not add your clarifications as answers any more. Edit your question instead, because that's how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have a stored procedure that takes your values, and then decides whether an INSERT or UPDATE is needed, based on the dates...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertOrUpdateData
    @FromDate DATE, @ToDate DATE, @NewAvail INT
AS 
   IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable
             WHERE Date_From = @FromDate AND Date_To = @ToDate)

      UPDATE dbo.YourTable
      SET Available = Available + @NewAvail
      WHERE Date_From = @FromDate AND Date_To = @ToDate

   ELSE

      INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Date_From, Date_To, Availability)
      VALUES(@FromDate, @ToDate, @NewAvail)
```

With this stored procedure, you can call

```
EXEC dbo.InsertOrUpdateData 
     @FromDate = '20110301', @ToDate = '20110305', @NewAvail = 42
```

If those dates already exists, that row will be **updated**, if those dates don't exist, a new row will be **inserted**. No trigger voodoo or anything like that needed....

Is that what you're looking for??

Comment: in this situation how we update availability? and display data like stage 3

Answer (score 0):

When you get a new row you need to do the following:

Using the new ValidFrom and ValidTo dates - Checking existing data for anything that either:

- Has a ValidFrom < new Validfrom and ValidTo >= new ValidFrom - if found, ValidTo should be set to 1 day before new ValidFrom.
- Has a ValidFrom >= new ValidFrom and ValidTo <= new ValidTo - if found, You might need to do check again to see if moving the dates would overlap previous entries
- Has a ValidFrom >= new ValidFrom and ValidFrom <= new ValidTo and ValidTo >= new ValidTo. This record might need to be split in two.
- etc - any other concievable combination of Date overlaps ...

I would rather recommend using a new table with day - available, giving one row per product per day, with the available measure. This way, any new entries with validfrom / validto can just write the available value for the relevant days for the relevant products.

`DayID ProductId Available`